# Rails "table-less" Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I'm focused on moving my logic into my models. I've already integrated Stripe Payments into my Rails 4 app and the interaction with Stripe's API is taken care of in one of my standard (table-backed) models.

However, I'm just beginning to think about whether I should introduce a table-less model for this scenario (perhaps `stripe.rb`) to take care of the API calls, create new Stripe customers, updates cards etc.

Anyone got any advice on this and if you recommend a new model could you highlight some areas that I will need to be aware of regarding table-less models.

Answer (score 2):

You could extract the logic for the api into a service object.

It's pretty simple. Just create a services folder in you app directory, any *.rb files you place in there will be autoloaded by default in rails 4.

checkout the following article for more ideas

http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

Comment: Looks interesting  - will have a closer look later this evening - thanks

Comment: I've got the services going to communicate with Stripe but any idea how to trap errors in a service class and return them to the controller? For instance I can't use the Flash or `errors.add` as I get an error.

Comment: you can `include ActiveModel::Validations` check out http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html