# Best way to update credit cards using Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm building a small payment processing module for fun using a mix of Ruby on Rails and Stripe and would like to have your input.

I'm not going to store credit card information for obvious reasons but the whole management of them has left me asking myself how it should be done:

**I want my users to be able to see and update their current card(s) from their account page.**

So far I'm displaying their respective credit card info which was pretty easy but updating has left me wondering if I should create an model-less controller with only the basic verbs to create/update/delete credit cards or use only the javascript provided by Stripe.

What would you expert recommend?

Thanks!
Francis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm certainly no expert but I created a service object to handle interaction with Stripe and everything works well. I have included a link below to my original question which you may have already seen. On it there is a link to another resource which you may find useful.

[Rails "table-less" Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250863/rails-table-less-model)

My service object looks like this:

```
class StripeCommunicator < ActiveRecord::Base
  def initialize()
    Stripe.api_key = ENV['STRIPE_API_KEY']
  end

  def method1

  end

  def method2

  end
end
```

and then I call it as follows:

```
StripeCommunicator.new().method_name(params)
```

Comment: Hi @tommyd456! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, well deserves an answer :)

Comment: I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around what to put in the services objet for the credit card processing. Would you mind posting part of your services objet here or on a gist? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @tommyd456 for posting your code, I was in the right direction! I will still need a controller to post credit card information to right? Unless I'm missing something here...

Comment: Yes you will still need your controllers - my second piece of code (the single line) is a call from a controller to the service object.

Comment: I've sent a quick message